# Illustrator text alignment - center to specific letter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I have a list of names that I want to align vertically with specific letters within each name ex:

```
   COACH BRIT
  COACH JESSIKA
       CASSIDY
      VICTORIA
```

In the list above the B, E, S, and T line up vertically to spell BEST. I want BEST to be centered on the artboard and it will be a different color. I've tried several methods of grouping, aligning to key objects etc. and have not been able to get this to work.

There have been other instances where I've wanted the entire design to move to center of the artboard based upon an object that isn't in the center of the graphic and it's the same issue. If only I could select a key object from within a group!

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Heather and welcome to GraphicDesign! You could try making each letter its own object and keep them in the same group. Let us know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than outlining text, it would be better to keep it editable. This way you have a little control if you decide to change the font, font weight, etc. I think the best way to achieve this result is to:

1. Separately type all 4 lines of text.
2. Then align using guides.
3. Draw a square that covers **BEST**.
4. Draw a square the size of the art board, centre align the smaller square to the larger square.
5. Now just delete the larger square and position **BEST** over the
   smaller square.
6. Delete the smaller square and you should have the effect you desire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to break each letter up into its own vector shape and typeset each letter (now a shape) individually to achieve the effect you are after.